# Quotient Maps problem

Tags: general-topology

Let $q: X \rightarrow Y  $ be any quotient map. For a subset $U \subseteq X$, show that the following are equivalent:

a) $U$ is saturated.

b) $U=q^{-1}(q(U))$

c) $U$ is a union of fibers.

d) if $x \in U$, then every point $x' \in X$ such that $q(x)=q(x') $ is also in $U$.

**Definition**:
Let $q: X \rightarrow Y$ is a map. Any subset of the form $q^{-1}(y) \subseteq X$ for some $y \in Y$ is called a **fiber of q**. 
A subset $U \subseteq X$ is said to be **saturated with respect to q** if $U = q^{-1}(V)$ for some $V \subseteq Y$.

draft 
proof of (b implies c): Suppose $U=q^{-1}(q(U)). $

I'm stuck and I'm not quite sure where to go for the proof. What's confusing me is that $q(U)$ is a subset of $Y$ and $q^{-1}(y)$ is a subset but $y$ is an element of $Y$. I can't let $y= q(U) $ since an element is not a set.

Any helpful hints and advice that will help guide toward the proof will be greatly appreciated. Please don't write out the entire proof as I want to figure it out and not have it spoiled for me.

Book is Topological Manifolds by John Lee.

Comment: You are free to use the identity $q^{-1}(y) = q^{-1}(\{y\})$.

Comment: is it safe to say that {y} = q(U)?

Comment: No, that's not safe at all: by definition $q(U) = \{q(x) \,\bigm|\, x \in U\}$, a subset of $Y$ which may have more than one point. There is definitely an abuse of notation going on with the symbol $q$: as defined it is a function $q : X \to Y$ with domain $X$ and range $Y$; but the same symbol is being reused as the induced function $q : \mathcal{P}X \to \mathcal{P}Y$ with domain the power set of $X$ and range the power set of $Y$. You have to keep your head on very straight if this confuses you, in which case perhaps you might even want to use a different letter for the second function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When $U$ is a subset of the domain $X$ of a function $q: X \to Y$, $q(U)$ is used (by abuse of notation) to mean the set of $y \in Y$ such that $y = q(x)$ for some $x \in U$. Similarly for $V \subseteq Y$, $q^{-1}(V)$ means the set of $x \in X$ such that $q(x) \in V$ (and so is a union of fibres, namely the fibres over the elements of $V$).